# Angular2/4 Visual Studio Code template navigation

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Which extension is responsible for component navigation in template view in Visual Studio?
What I mean exactly, how to setup VS Code to be able to `ctrl`+`LMB` or `F12` when highlighting custom component. So far I'm getting:
[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template ?

Answer (score 0):

As steted by Gosha_Fighten - `Angular Language Service` extension do the trick. Thank you for help!
BTW, this crucial feature is not stated in any "top 10 extensions for Angular", I think it deserves more tribute...

Edited:
Seems like answer is on official Angular.io pages now: [Link](https://angular.io/guide/language-service)